# How can I let the cursor to move in left direction while deleting the input text?

Tags: jquery

This is the function I am using to delete input text. This function helps me delete the text but at the same time it moves in right direction. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
function backSpace(){
  var txt = $("#dialpadinput");
  var startPos = txt[0].selectionStart;
  var endPos = txt[0].selectionEnd;
  var scrollPos = txt[0].scrollTop;
  //console.log("start: " + startPos + " end: " + endPos + " scrollPos: " + scrollPos);
  if (endPos - startPos > 0) {
    txt.val(txt.val().slice(0, startPos) + txt.val().slice(endPos, 100));
  } else if (endPos > 0) {
    txt.val(txt.val().slice(0, startPos-1) + txt.val().slice(startPos, 100));
  } else {
    startPos = txt.val().length+1;
  }
  txt.focus();
  txt[0].setSelectionRange(startPos-1,startPos-1);
}
```

Comment: What moves in the right direction?  The cursor?